Support vector regression performance on random data
I trained a SVR model with random values(a random time series) and test it with another random set to check how is the performance of SVR in predicting random data.
when I plot the test data and prediction test data, it was surprising to see the test data and predict of test data are very similar? how is it possible?
because I trained it in one random data and test it on another random data!
